# Assigning different code to update() of different objects of the same class

Tags: processing

Would it be possible to load different code into the update function of different objects of the same class? Ie:

```java
Button button = new Button();


class Button {
    // constructor, variables, etc
    void update() {
        //load code specific to the object
    }
}
```

Could I create a pointer to an external function (ie in a different file)? I know I can't point in java but is there anything similar?

Comment: Not really what you ask, but maybe a [Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) could be an approach. And [this](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/9308#Comment_9308) thread at processing forum might be usefull also

Comment: Also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Comment: That seems very complex, I guess I'll just do the conditional approach. It would be neat if you could have a function variable that points to a specific function, then write the functions outside of the class.

Comment: Not really as complex as it seems, have a look in the code below, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

A class is used to define certain behavior. Of course, not all instances of a class have to behave *exactly* the same (button1 displays red, button2 displays blue, for instance), but it is still the same basic behavior. A button would not act like a tree, and it doesn't make sense to have `button1.func()` do one thing and `button2.func()` do something completely different. Having said that, if you want some method of two buttons to do different things, you have two options: either split the behavior into two methods, or (and this is probably what you want) have the buttons contain an indentifier variable and have the method contain a conditional based on that variable. Here's an example:

```java
class Button {
  // ID is 1 for green and 2 for blue
  int ID;
  Button(int id){
    ID = id;
  }
  void update(){
    if(ID == 1){ //green
      //do something
    else if(ID == 2){
      //do something else
    }
  }
}
```

To answer your question: dynamic code loading (eg from a text file) is a bad idea for lots of reasons. First, it's not clear what the code would do if you read over it (you'd have to go look at another file to find out), and second, it would be a *huge* security flaw because someone could replace your text file with something malicious and you'd have uncontrolled code execution.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample interface code**

```java
Button r = new RedButt(); // note Buton = new RedButt...
Button b = new BlueButt();
Button[] buttons = new Button[2];

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
buttons[0] = r;
buttons[1] = b;
for(Button b : buttons){
  b.display();
}
}


interface Button{
  void display();
}


class RedButt implements Button{

  RedButt(){
  }

  void display(){
    fill(255,0,0);
    ellipse(random(25, width-25), random(25, height -25), 50, 50);
  }
}



class BlueButt implements Button{

  BlueButt(){
  }

  void display(){
    fill(0, 0, 255);
    ellipse(random(25, width-25), random(25, height -25), 50, 50);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but it requires two classes, one for each button, the specific problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: As I said, not exactly what you asked for... :) You have two classes, but you can access them as one. Still 2 classes to maintain and write though.

Comment: Can you have variables in the interface? such that the only thing in each class would be the constructor and any independent functions/variables.

Comment: Apparently in Java8 you can... [default Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Comment: What about making an array of objects, where each one has its own class? ie. buttons[] where buttons[0] is a RedButt, buttons[1] is a GreenButt etc.

Comment: Well this is exactly what is being done in the code above, isn't it? Am I missing something?